# Frequency histogram/bar-chart in Python from two lists

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graphing

I've been researching this for a little while now and it seems there is no simple implementation for what I want to do, which I would assume is a very simple and common idea.

I have two lists sorted in regard to each other, one with Strings (names from a dataset) and the other with ints (frequency in which they appear in the dataset). I have seen no simple way to plot the two lists against each other, with the Strings occupying the x-axis and a bar going up to its corresponding frequency on the y-axis, provided by my other list.

Surely something as simple as plotting two lists against each other in this fashion shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: Why do you say it is difficult?  What did you try? In how far did it not work?

Comment: Hope you have tried with matplotlib ?

Comment: The duplicate question (which didn't show up in my own searching annoyingly) showed me how to do it. I had no idea how to use plt.xticks from its documentation. Point still stands, this should be a one step solution.